# I want to keep data in my database after deletion and track it. How can I achive this goal?

Tags: python, django, django-models, soft-delete

i have a simple model Category. I want to soft delete instances and keep track of them in my db

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django_currentuser.middleware import get_current_user, get_current_authenticated_user

from django_currentuser.db.models import CurrentUserField


class Category(models.Model):
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField("Created At", auto_now_add = True, null = True)
    created_by = CurrentUserField(related_name='created_by')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField("Updated At", auto_now = True, null = True)
    updated_by = CurrentUserField(related_name='updated_by')
    deleted_on = 
    deleted_by = 

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can soft_delete the object by adding boolean value

```
   delete =  models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
```

and deleted_by

```
deleted_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

and deleted_on

```
deleted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Inside your views you have to filter the data as Category.objects.filter(delete=False)